# How do I output monthly rainfall as "*" using arrays C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have created a program which allows a user to enter the rainfall over the course of a year. The program is then meant to output a chart as well as summarized data such as average, maximum, minimum and total rainfall.

While all of my outputs based upon data works, the actual chart which is meant to display the numbers inputted with asterisks isn't working.

I can't quite understand where I have gone wrong. I have linked an example output of the "*" table as well as my actual code below. Any help would be much appreciated. I am a beginner to C# by the way.
[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hunuN.jpg)

```
        int[] monthrainfall = new int[12];
        int i;
        double average;
        int total = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int min = Int32.MaxValue;
        string bar = "";

        //title
        Console.Write("\n\nRainfall Data:\n");
        Console.Write("**************\n");

        //asks user to input names
        Console.Write("Enter Rainfall for the year:\n");

        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter rainfall for month {0}: ", i + 1);
            monthrainfall[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //outputs rainfall results
        Console.WriteLine("\nRainfall Chart");
        Console.WriteLine("**************");

        //outputs results for each month
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Month {0}: ", i + 1);
            bar = bar + "*";
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ", bar[i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nSummary data");
        Console.WriteLine("**************");

        //calculates the maximum rainfall
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < 12; index2++) //inline variable declaration
        {
            if (monthrainfall[index2] > max) max = monthrainfall[index2];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The maximum rainfall was: " + max);

        //calculates the minimum rainfall

        for (int index3 = 0; index3 < 12; index3++) //inline variable declaration
        {
            if (monthrainfall[index3] < min) min = monthrainfall[index3];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The minimum rainfall was: " + min);

        //calculates average rainfall
        for (int index = 0; index < 12; index++)
        {
            total = total + monthrainfall[index];
        }
        average = (total) / 12;

        Console.WriteLine("The average rainfall was: " + average);
        Console.WriteLine("The total rainfall was: " + total);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As this seems like a homework, I would rather give you hints. so, in the code that generates rainfall chart you are not making use of `monthrainfall[i]` , also you might need a nested loop.

Comment: The `System.String` class (aka the `string` class) has a constructor that takes a `char` and an integer count. If you say `var lineOfGraph = new string ('*', 5);` you'll get a string that looks like `"*****"`

Comment: My program still doesn't run...

Comment: Since string is basically an array of `char`, what you're printing in `bar[i]` is the character at position `[i]` thus will only result in a single asterisk `*`.

Comment: I still don't understand. How do I fix my error?

Comment: Can anyone please give me the solution because it is killing me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {   //loop every month
        Console.Write("Month {0}: ", i + 1);
bar = "";
for(int stars = 0; stars < monthrainfall[i]; stars++)
{
    bar = bar + "*";
}
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ", bar[i]);
    }
```

but as @Flydog57 said, use the string constructor instead of the additional for-loop

Comment: this code doesn't run...

Answer (score 0):

All of the explanation is going to take place in this part of code

```
//outputs results for each month
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Month {0}: ", i + 1);
    bar = bar + "*";
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ", bar[i]);
}
```

---

**Part 1:**
on `bar = bar + "*";` you are adding only one `*` for each iteration of the loop. However, what you want is to add the number based on what have been entered in `monthrainfall`.

As @Flydog57 suggested, the modification would be
`bar = new string('*', monthrainfall[i]);`

---

**Part 2:**
on `Console.WriteLine("{0} ", bar[i]);` you are only printing one `*` as you have selected the element `bar[i]` of the string `bar`.

The modification would be `Console.WriteLine("{0} ", bar);`

---

Comment: Thank you! I see where I went wrong now. I am very grateful for your help! Hopefully one day I can help others once I become a better programmer!